# How to display an emoji in a Facebook Messenger bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm trying to display an emoji in a Facebook Messenger bot made in NodeJS but I cannot figure out how to turn chars like http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F382 into a string I could send via the API.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280834/sending-emojis-with-facebook-messenger-api-and-botkit ?

Comment: Thank you @dan, Sriram answer did it for me, but thanks a lot for looking it up.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the emojis are not supported. You will get snowflakes if you try this

```
decodeURI('\u2744')
```

whereas,

```
decodeURI('\uF382')
```

is not working.

Thanks
Sriram

Comment: Many thanks Sriram! That works fine for snowflakes. I'm however trying to display balloons (http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F388) that I have seen in a Messenger bot app, with no success. Are you able to make it work?

Comment: Thanks for checking, there must be a way since I saw it in an app. Will update here if I find (and please do the same if you do).